# Grid in CSS-Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm searching for a solution (maybe grid-css?) to style the following html

```html
<section>
    <img src=""/>
    <img src=""/>
    <img src=""/>
    <img src=""/>
    <img src=""/>
    <img src=""/>
    <img src=""/>
    <img src=""/>
</section>
```

into the following grid-view without changing the html:

[image]

Comment: Try this tool: https://grid.layoutit.com/

Comment: How about using Bootstrap framework?

Comment: bootstrap is in this case way too large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by using `display: grid` and `:nth-child`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: .5rem;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.grid .item:nth-child(4n + 1) {
  grid-row: span 2;
}
.grid .item:nth-child(4n) {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container grid">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using your exact same HTML you provided and only CSS to build your layout.

Note the tool used for this code is this: https://grid.layoutit.com/

```css
section {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 1px 1px;
    grid-template-areas:
      "one one two three"
      "one one four four"
      "five five six seven"
      "five five eight eight";
}

section > img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

img:nth-child(1){grid-area: one}
img:nth-child(2){grid-area: two}
img:nth-child(3){grid-area: three}
img:nth-child(4){grid-area: four}
img:nth-child(5){grid-area: five}
img:nth-child(6){grid-area: six}
img:nth-child(7){grid-area: seven}
img:nth-child(8){grid-area: eight}
```

```html
<section>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500"/>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x250"/>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x250"/>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x250"/>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500"/>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x250"/>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x250"/>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x250"/>
</section>
```

Comment: The disadvantage of this solution is, that this section can have a max of 8 images. This doesn't scale for e.g. 16 images

Comment: In this case you could use the solution of @fen1x. In my answer I provide solution to the exact problem you exposed to us. If no features provided, we do not have a crystal ball to see what the person makes the question has in his mind :)